# Are mongodb aggregation pipelines something to avoid if possible?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I assume (please correct me if I am wrong) that all aggregation pipelines calculations take place in the mongodb server, not in the client.

This question is about **best practises** and computational **efficiency**.

Take for instance a document like this:

```
{
  _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectID,
  name: 'James Brown',
  job: 'singer',
  relationships: [
    { type: 'wife', duration: 2 },
    { type: 'manager', duration: 10 },
    { type: 'friend', duration: 40 }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Where we want to have a new document field which will represent the total duration (in years) of all relationships.

My question is; What is more efficient in a situation like before, running aggregation pipelines **every time** or calculating client sided **once**?

By calculating client-sided I mean specifically, fetching the document from database, doing the calculations with *Javascript* and finally updating the document with the new field.

Comment: In other words, in which circumstances are aggregation pipelines OK to use?

Comment: The "client-side" thingie you described is called pre-aggregation. It has it's usecases but it's a bit more complex than you described. You will need to take into account race conditions and concurrent updates. Generally speaking it's more efficient but it's less flexible and the maintenance cost is quite high. Usually you would go with aggregation and optimize it only when you notice performance issues.

Comment: whatever data you can pre-calculate before storage and retrieve via covered index query (to avoid collection scan/fetch) would be the most efficient (when possible). but in your example, it's best to store a `StartDate` and then calculate the duration during presentation on the client-side (not even in the web api). offload calculations/work like these to the presentation layer freeing up mongodb to be just a dumb storage/retrieval mechanism.

Comment: This is a case of a design pattern called as Computed Pattern: [Model Computed Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-computed-data/).